# Using nodemailer with handlebars for dynamic emails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I'm having an issue and I can't seem to narrow down what exactly I'm doing wrong. When I run my code, this is the error I get:

`[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\emailtest\main.handlebars'] { errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\emailtest\\main.handlebars' }`

Here is my code:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const hbs = require("nodemailer-express-handlebars");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: "useremail",
    pass: "userpassword",
  },
  //   tls: {
  //     rejectUnauthorized: false,
  //   },
});

transporter.use(
  "compile",
  hbs({
    viewEngine: "express-handlebars",
    viewPath: "views",
  })
);

const mailOptions = {
  from: "myemailhere",
  to: "receiverpassword",
  subject: "Automated Email",
  template: "index",
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(
    `Listening at http://localhost:${port}`
  );
});
```

Folder structure:

```
server.js
views
    -index.handlebars
```

Without using Handlebars, I can send emails just fine, but being that I need a way to fill in HTML dynamically, I think Handlebars would be the best option if I can just get it working. Any insight would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try passing a full path? Just a thought.

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky Unfortunately I've already tried that, thanks though

Comment: Also, `viewEngine` is not a string. It is either an instance of express-handlebars or an options obj. You can define your layouts dir there as well. Not sure what exactly is causing it to go with the default location, but I would poke around there

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path');

const handlebarOptions = {
    viewEngine: {
        extName: ".handlebars",
        partialsDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "views"),
        defaultLayout: false,
    },
    viewPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "views"),
    extName: ".handlebars",
};

trasnporter.use('compile', hbs(handlebarOptions));
```